# How to measure distance between coordinate data (x-Point, y-point) to a specific point of reference (using R)

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, geospatial

I need help! I have a list of points (mydata X, Y = latitude, longitude) which I want to set in relation towards a single Point (for example 287, 347). I just want to measure (and plot) the distance between the list of points towards this single point of reference. But I don't get it. I tried PCA, but there I can't set my specific point of reference.
Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

mydata:

```
X,Y
260,204
409,208
260,60
272,181
367,257
315,208
381,294
66,333
246,220
330,207
342,304
...
```

Comment: Just calculate it: `mydata$distance = sqrt((mydata$X - 287)^2 + (mydata$Y - 347)^2)`. You don't need PCA to calculate distance.

Comment: In the future, please think about making *minimal* examples. There's no reason to share 276 lines of data when 6 will do.

Comment: Then I get an error: '`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "distance", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 276'

Comment: Make sure you are referring to the columns with the correct names. I edited my comment, but when I put it up initially I used lowercase `x` and `y`, but your post seems to indicate that they are uppercase `X` and `Y`.

Comment: ok thanks. but how can I plot this? I am thinking on something like a headmap

Comment: If you *know* what kind of plot you want, then we can surely help you make it. If don't know, then you need to decide. What kind of plot to choose depends wholly on what you want to communicate or explore.

Comment: These are clearly not any sort of latitude or longitude values that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry), this is a trivial calculation:

```
mydata$distance = sqrt((mydata$X - 287)^2 + (mydata$Y - 347)^2)
```

I'm not sure what sort of plot you would like of distance - perhaps a histogram?

```
hist(mydata$distance)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! do You have any idea how to plot this as a headmap?

Comment: I'm sure you can find some example of how to make heatmaps in R. This is unusual data for a heatmap, which is usually used to show density of points, not some function of points. Think about what you want on the x axis, on the y axis, and what color means.

Comment: If these were latitude and longitude, which they clearly were not, then it would have made more sense to load a package that would calculate Great Circle distances.

Comment: They are alike latitude and longitudes (but not related to geo data). What do you mean by "calculate Great Circle distances"?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the euclidean distance, why not just make your own function to do it?

```
distance <- function(x, y, home= c(0,0)) sqrt((x-home[1])^2+(y-home[2])^2)
plot(distance(400*runif(100), 400*runif(100), c(287, 347)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by compute the distance like Georg said and then by using the density function.

```
mydata <- read.table("blabla.csv", sep=",")

mydata$distance = sqrt((mydata$V1 -555)^2 + (mydata$V2 - 85)^2)

d <- density(mydata$distance)

plot(d)
```

I think this is something like a Kernel regression (KDE)?.